# Error in code mentioned, it says unexpected symbol

Tags: datatable

Unable to run the below code:

loc <- sample(state_table$key, no_of_recs, replace=T, prob=c(2,2,1,1,1)) time_month <- sample(month_table$key, no_of_recs, replace=T) time_year <- sample(c(2012, 2013), no_of_recs, replace=T) prod <- sample(prod_table$key, no_of_recs, replace=T, prob=c(1, 3, 2)) unit <- sample(c(1,2), no_of_recs, replace=T, prob=c(10, 3)) amount <- unit*prod_table[prod,]$price sales <- data.frame(month=time_month, year=time_year, loc=loc, prod=prod, unit=unit, amount=amount)

Comment: what are you doing here? can you elaborate? where is the error? what have you tried so far to solve the error?

Comment: I was trying to run that code, create a data frame. It's sorted now. Thanks